# Text Justification function in Android

Tags: text-justify

When i using this code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
      tv.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD);
}
```

i got this error when release

```
 error: cannot find symbol
      tv.setJustificationMode(JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD)
                        ^


symbol:   variable JUSTIFICATION_MODE_INTER_WORD
```

please help me

Comment: Please add complete code of your file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.